# How to make a sidebar menu like Spotify has with IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Like the iPad version. A sidebar menu always on the left and have few buttons on it. I have no clue how to make one like this. should I customise one myself?
I find this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/, but on the step "control-drag from SWRevealViewController to the Menu view controller", seems not working for me.

Comment: Check out CocoaControls: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=sidebar
I'm sure you'll find something there that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey to i've experienced the current library so what you have to do is the following in `storyboard`:

From document outline menu select `Viewcontroller` which is `SWRevealViewController` and ctrl-drag to the `Menucontroller`. it should work fine :)

[image]

**Update :**

First you should download the library from github called `SWRevealViewController` and integrate it with your app.then you will be able to see it in storyboard.

- I added bridge.h file which uses the objective-c library into swift.

I've integrated the the library with the project and you may download it here : https://yadi.sk/d/Ux05nSgRioBzV

**Update 2:** To show the menu from the right you only have to :

1- set the segue identifier to : `sw_right` instead of `sw_rear` :

[image]

2- In your UIViewController change menuButton action from `revealToggle` into `rightRevealToggle` :

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "rightRevealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}
```

Run it and it should work fine !

Comment: It said select “reveal view controller set segue”. But I don't have that option,

Comment: I have reveal view controller push controller and reveal view controller set controller

Comment: @Aaoli really appreciate, it works now, the description and the options i have are different, but all good now, thank you so much.

Comment: one more question, any idea about how to make the side bar on the right. found this  [link](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/185) but don't understand how.